# Remove all spaces and tabs from ONLY specified segment line?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I use Notepad++ v8.1.1.

How to find a specific segment and remove all spaces and tabs from ONLY that segment?

E.g. I want to find all "EQD" lines and remove all spaces and tabs from JUST those lines.

Sample data:

```
EQD+CN+ZMLU XXXXXXX+45GP+++5  
NAD+CA+ZMLU:172:ZZZ  
LOC+147+0260808::5  
FTX+AAA+++ALUMINUM ARTICLES  
MEA+WT++KGM:16549  
LOC+9+DOHAI:139:6  
LOC+11+USSAV:139:6  
RFF+BM:1  
EQD+CN+ZMLU XXXXXXX+45GP+++5  
NAD+CA+ZMLU:172:ZZZ  
LOC+147+0260202::5  
FTX+AAA+++ALCOHOLIC BEVERAGES  
MEA+WT++KGM:27797  
LOC+9+JMKIN:139:6  
LOC+11+USSAV:139:6  
RFF+BM:1  
EQD+CN+ZMLUXXXXXXX+45GP+++5  
NAD+CA+ZMLU:172:ZZZ
```

Comment: Can there be more than one space/tab in the line?

Comment: Does "EQD" appear only at the beginning of a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "EQD" only appears at the beginning of line, the following would work:

**Find what:** `(^EQD\S*)(($)|(\s))`
**Replace with:** `$1$3`

*If you have more than one space/tab per line, you will need to click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> several times.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for recursive regex:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^EQD\b|\G(?!^))\S*\K\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    ^           # beginning of line
    EQD         # literally EQD
    \b          # word boundary mandatory if you don't want to match EQDXX
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    (?!^)       # not at the beginning of line
)           # end group
\S*         # 0 or more non space character
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces (white space or tab)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]